# More control over my local server

Tags: linux, security, clearos

im running a clearOS server on my local network (small company of 10 developers) we use it as a developement server to test our work and show it to clients in test process each developer has a unique username and password to access the ftp/http/smb.
the problem is when one of the developer runs a non safe code (lets assume it is a php code) like running a infinite loop! the server completely crashes for all and im not able to identify who is the the faulty developer!! how can that be solved ? thanks in advance

**My server's info**

1. clearOS server
2. RAM 16GB
3. SSD 1TB (2 partitions)

**Apps installed:**

1. proftpd,
2. gitlab,
3. apache,
4. mariadb

**Users:**

1. physical root user and
2. 10 virtual user (using ldap) 
   *each user has a unique password*

Comment: "Whodunnit" should be determineable by asking the devs.  Being unwilling to admit a mistake in their code would be poisonous attitude in a dev.  Segregating each dev to a separate webserver would remove any need to ask, and remove the stigma of "Ok, who just crashed the server and cost me 3 hours work?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your problem(s)

You've stated your main problem as

> when one of the developer runs a non safe code (lets assume it is a php code) like running a infinite loop! the server completely crashes for all and im not able to identify who is the the faulty developer!

Because development code can always crash or hang, you are effectively dealing with two different problems:

1. Processes of different users should not interfere with each other and not take all resources, starving others or even crashing the server.
2. Identifying the user who "did it".

If you solve the second problem, you still need to solve the first; but if you solve the first, you don't need to solve the second one anymore, so I focus on solving the first here (also, solving problems without confronting people about bad things is always easier and gets less confrontation).

---

## Possible solutions

You have three main paths to choose from when isolating user actions from one another:

1. **Processes & file system:** The simplest and oldest way of separation is to give resources to each different user on a multi-user UNIX system.

   - uptime365 did already give suggestions for `ulimit`, I just want to add that you have to make sure that your applications also use those users (instead of generic daemon users for each service) and that they do not want to start processes with other user accounts. Because of this downside this approach is seldom used today, except for simple things like build scripts without a continuous delivery infrastructure.
   - File system quotas are more useful today, as storage is still a primary resource and it works with nearly all applications.
2. **Applications:** Most of the software you access already has built-in user and quota management, but you need to manage/configure it separately. For example, the database can set quotas and permissions on each user and [limit what he can do](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html). The downside besides different configuration (which could be unified by scripts or applications) is that not all software is equally well equipped. For example, GitLab seems to still [not support disk quotas](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3739#). You will have to evaluate your error causes and see if the given features are good enough for your case.
3. **Containers & VMs:** Leveraging virtualization (either full virtualization like KVM or ESXi; or containerization like Solaris Zones, FreeBSD Jails, Linux LXC, or application-based like Docker et al.) allows you to present each user with a full virtual system where he can do anything you allow him to, but limit his resources so that he does not disturb the other users. It is the most advanced form of segregation, because essentially each user has his own machine and does not interfere at all (if configured correctly), so you also have different configuration and runtime options, different networking, different hard drives and so on. The downside of this solution is that it has the highest overhead in configuration and resource usage of those three.

Of course, combinations are always possible, as the approaches work on different layers. For example, you could use containers so that everyone has his own webserver, but let all users use the same database to save resources (database access is faster than with several different databases), limited by database quotas.

---

## What do do in your case?

As you see, the possibilities are many and each of them is considerable effort to implement, so you need to narrow it down:

- First analyze what problems you are encountering exactly. Take a look at your process (or if you don't have one, ask your colleagues how they do their work) and identify the problems that arise (disk space runs out when running test cases, endless loops reserve too much memory, web server crashes because of uncaught exceptions or bad architecture, etc.).
- After you know what you are up against, think about how to mitigate the problems while keeping it simple. Configuration takes roughly the same time for 10 PCs as for 100, so you should first try the simple stuff (most of the time, that is already enough). Disk space can be limited by user quotas while endless loops as well as memory over-consumption can be caught by unit tests prematurely (executed as local user instead of on web server).
- If this is not enough, you can think about implementing bigger and better solutions, like containers. Initially, you will lose time, but in the long run it may pay off - depending on your specific situation, of course.

Comment: @MedAbida Implications of #3 mean more hardware.  While 1 server can host 10 VMs, with only 16 GB RAM and 1 TB storage, it's not going to be robust enough for 10 devs.  They will use all of the VMs at once...they're devs.  For a virtualized solution, you will need to think in terms of 2-3 servers with a total in the range of 256 GB RAM.  If the hardware cost is 'doable', this provides the best segregation, and the virtualization model is the easiest to manage (for the admin).  Set up shared resources on one VM, then assign each dev a VM. Pick your favorite configuration management & backups.

Comment: @MedAbida also, if the only part that is different for each dev, then containers are definitely the route.  More complicated for the admin than virtualization, it would also require less hardware to upgrade to containerized system.  (Though still more than what you have.)

Comment: @Xalorous I would also suggest the container route, especially as all his developers seem to already use the same OS (I assume it is Linux). Although you don't need that much RAM if your goal is to debug code - less memory means memory errors surface earlier. Also overprovisioning would be a possibility, as normally developers do not run their code at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As a preventive measure you should look into ulimits if you want to set specific set of limits to users. You can set process / CPU / memory limits.

Please refer [this link](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm)

The other way is to monitor the resource usage of the system with an external monitoring tool,( most common example : nagios/nrpe ) which can alert you in case a resource threshold is crossed.

Comment: i think that nagios is not supported in clearOS and how can i track the source of the problem (which user reached the threshold)
using ulimit will only allow me to set a limit to the apache process or the ftp process ! but not per user!! please keep in mind that im using ldap to manage virtual user

Comment: ulimits can most certainly impose restrictions on individual users, and imposes limits on apache via the apache *user*.